# How to cache spa.html only with networkfirst or how to configure offline mod with ssr

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, service-worker, workbox

I have an application with ssr, it turns out that the page, when there is Internet, is always given with correct markup. The problem is that I do not know how to force the workbox
Give away spa.html only when there is clearly no network.

I did:

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(
   workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL('/spa.html')
)
```

But it is cached once and then the user always receives this file, even when there is a network, the user receives the file without markup on all pages: `<div id="app"></div>`

I want to cache and give spa.html file only when the user has network problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      new RegExp('/spa.html'),
      new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst()
);
```

Refer : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_first_network_falling_back_to_cache